# How can I allow users to reference variables and other data structures via input?

Tags: windows, function, input, exec, python-3.5

example.py

```
dumpVar = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

def examineVar():
  container = input('Which var would you like to examine? ')
  for i in range (len(container)):
    print(container[i])
                                                                                            .
```

Python 3.5 (32bit)

```
>>> exec(open(r'c:\users\me\desktop\code\example.py').read())
>>> examineVar()
Which variable would you like to examine? _
                                                                                            .
```

---

Here's the run down --I have a .py file named 'example' that I'm running from the interpreter to load a code environment I can work with. This particular environment contains a single array (already populated), and a single function armed with some basic commands meant to return information about the input one line at a time.

What I want to do is input the variable name I have created by the script, and have the function handle printing the contents.

I realize I could just as easily do `>>> dumpVar`, to see the array displayed in one line --but I'm trying to figure out how to pass... I guess meta information... through to the interpreter via user input. If that makes any sense.

Anyway I've been trying to use `exec()`, but anywhere I place it in the function tends to produce exceptions, and the only time it didn't produce an exception, it just printed one character of `dumpVar` at a time, creating a new line each time (the new line being desired behavior of course).

So, how can I modify my function to produce the contents of my variable, rather then the characters of my input string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update from OP's comment. His intention is to reference variables through input, and his original title did not make this clear. The solution is to implement a dictionary, referencing the objects via a string key:

```
list_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

my_variables = {'list_a' : list_a}

def examineVar():
    for i in my_variables[input('>>> ')]:
        print(i, end='')

    print('\n')

examineVar()
```

Output:

```
python3 variable_referencing.py
>>> list_a
abcdef
```

---

Use [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#func-list):

```
>>> x = 'hello'
>>> list(x)
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>>
```

Modified Function:

```
def examineVar():
  container = list(input('Which var would you like to examine? '))
  for i in range (len(container)):
    print(container[i])
```

Furthermore, it is unnecessary to define a range in your iterable `(range(len(container))` this will suffice:

```
for i in container:
    print(i)
```

If you want to know the index of the item as well as the item, use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, v in enumerate(container):
    print("Index:{} - Value:{}".format(i, v)
```

Comment: I thought for sure this was the answer after looking up list() in the python docs, but when I tried it it produced `d u m p V a r` again, where the spaces in this comment represent new lines in the interpreter.

Comment: I was unaware of what you intended to do, initially. Consider using a dictionary, I'll update my answer. Also, to remove the new line when printing, use `print(object[,end=])` where `end=` is ` '' `.

Comment: The function is meant to return the contents of the variable name input by the user one line at a time.

Comment: The code I added will allow you to reference dumpVar through a dictionary, that maps the string `'dumpVar'` to the variable `dumpVar`'s location in memory.

Comment: Finally got a chance to test. This is exactly the sort of solution I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Of course! I learned some new things as well by figuring it out!